# Can anyone please explain this following programming questioñ?

Tags: python

Question: Define a Python function named calculate_tax() which accepts one parameter, income, and returns the income tax. Income is taxed according to the following rule: the first $250,000 is taxed at 40% and any remaining income is taxed at 80%. For example, calculate_tax(100000) should return $100,000 * 0.40 = $40,000, while calculate_tax(300000) should return $250,000 * 0.40 + 50,000 * 0.80 = $140,000.

**My question is simple, does the question ask for me to print out the whole math operation `$100,000 * 0.40 = $40,000`, or just the final answer`$40,000`?**

Comment: It says create a function which "returns the income tax", not "returns the whole equation." So probably just the final answer, $40,000.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's asking for an interpretation of a question from a problem set; there's no programming question here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does say "should return $250,000 * 0.40 + 50,000 * 0.80 = $140,000," but all your function should actually `return` is the final value of `250000`. The function should simply do the calculation and `return` the result. The equation is written out in order to help you create the function, not as an output requirement.

However, the best person to clarify assignments is the teacher who assigned them.

Answer (score 0):

Is not it? like this:

```
def calculate_tax(income=250000):
    tax = 0
    if income <= 250000:
        tax = income * 0.4
    else:
        tax = 250000 * 0.4 + (income - 250000) * 0.8
    return int(tax)

print calculate_tax(100000) # 40000
print calculate_tax(300000) # 140000
```